# Receiving Grub message without ever installing Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, disk

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to Ubuntu. I keep procrastinating on learning, sorry I'm digressing. My Windows 7 HD failed. I booted into Ubuntu 16.4  and retrieved my important files. I installed windows 10 onto a new hard drive. I didn't install Ubuntu. I just ran it from a CD. Now when I boot up Win10, I get,

error: no such partition. 
Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue>

I've tried:
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd

The old hard drive is still connected and I just received an message about it. Also, the HD's might be connected to their original Sata Ports. Any and all help would be awesome. Again, thank you.

Comment: This is not the same problem. Since I never installed Ubuntu. I only used Ubuntu from a CD.

Comment: If you never installed Ubuntu, the problem you're having has to do with different requirements for Windows 7 (BIOS/Legacy) and Windows 10 (UEFI). That said, the fact that you *used* Ubuntu doesn't qualify your question for AU. It's all about Windows(es) and as such off topic.

Comment: "Any and all help would be awesome." You accidentally installed grub because you are getting a `grub rescue>` prompt so even though you "only used Ubuntu from a CD" you need to uninstall Grub and use the Windows bootloader.

Comment: Thanks karel, that worked. I REALLY appreciate your time and help. And a special thanks to you MichaelBay. I feel so welcome here :-[

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 setup typically formats and partitions the hard drive in such a way that sometimes the only option for the boot to work effectively is with Secure Boot activation. If your computer's BIOS has this option, enable it to verify that Windows 10 will boot properly.